# how to convert ereg_replace regex for preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

can any one replace ereg to preg values in this code:

```
$phpAds_config['url_prefix'] = strtolower(eregi_replace("^([a-z]+)/.*$", "\\1://",
$HTTP_SERVER_VARS['SERVER_PROTOCOL'])) . $host .
ereg_replace("/admin/install.php(\?.*)?$", "", $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['PHP_SELF']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just surround your regex with delimiters:

```
$phpAds_config['url_prefix'] = strtolower(
    preg_replace("~^([a-z]+)/.*$~i", "\1://", $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['SERVER_PROTOCOL'])).
    $host. 
    preg_replace("~/admin/install.php(\?.*)?$~", "", $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['PHP_SELF']);
```